# The error message like "non-numeric argument to binary operator" comes out when I use "Delt" function

Tags: r, zoo

I got error message like "non-numeric argument to binary operator" when I typed the code below.  Much appreciated for your comment in advance!

```
library(zoo)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(quantmod)
price_m = read.csv("F:/R_Doc/price_m.csv", row.names=1, header=TRUE)
price_m[is.na(price_m)] = 0
price_kospi = read.csv("F:/R_Doc/kospi.csv", row.names=1, header=TRUE)
ro = dim(price_m)[1]
co = dim(price_m)[2]
ret_kospi = Delt(price_kospi)
```

Error in unclass(x2)/Lag(x1, K.) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator

My data are stored in the file `kospi.csv` and have the below values:

```
Date    KOSPI200
12/31/1994  113.51
1/31/1995   102.85
2/28/1995   98.9
3/31/1995   104.86
4/30/1995   101.78
5/31/1995   99.96
6/30/1995   101.3
7/31/1995   105.69
8/31/1995   103.45
9/30/1995   111.97
10/31/1995  113.08
11/30/1995  104.82
```

Comment: Try `Delt(price_kospi$KOSPI200])` You probably would also want to convert this dataframe into an XTS

Comment: It works!  Much appreciated for your help^^